# How to fix this in C#: main.cs(18,5): warning CS0642: Possible mistaken empty statement

Tags: c#

I am working on a BMI calculation assignment using the If-else statements. I get an error

> CS1525 unexpected symbol 'else'

and warning

> CS0642: Possible mistaken empty statement

This is a BMI calculation in C#

```
bmi = (weight * 703) / height^2;

if (bmi < 18.5);
{
    Console.WriteLine("Underweight"); 

else if (bmi <= 25)
    Console.WriteLine("Optimal"); 

else if (bmi > 25);
    Console.WriteLine("Overweight");
}
```

Mono C# compiler version 4.6.2.0

```
mcs -out:main.exe main.cs
```

> main.cs(20,5): warning CS0642: Possible mistaken empty statement
>   main.cs(23,6): error CS1525: Unexpected symbol `else'
>   main.cs(27,13): warning CS0642: Possible mistaken empty statement
>   Compilation failed: 1 error(s), 2 warnings
>   compiler exit status 1

Comment: Use braces and your life is going to be easier :) By the way the `^` operator in C# is the [XOR operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/boolean-logical-operators#logical-exclusive-or-operator-) not power. Use [`Math.Pow`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.math.pow?view=netframework-4.8) if you want to raise a number to a specific power.

Comment: if (...); - is an empty statement. should be read as 'if [something] then do [nothing]'

Comment: your `else if` need to come after the first `if`, not inside of it

Answer (score 2):

I dont have Mono compiler, but try this:

```
bmi = (weight * 703) / Math.Pow(height,2);

if (bmi < 18.5)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Underweight"); 
}
else if (bmi <= 25)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Optimal");
}
else if (bmi > 25)
{
  Console.WriteLine("Overweight");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you please update the code as below and try -

bmi = (weight * 703) / Math.Pow(height,2);

if (bmi < 18.5)
  Console.WriteLine("Underweight");

else if (bmi <= 25)
  Console.WriteLine("Optimal");

else if (bmi > 25)
  Console.WriteLine("Overweight");

Answer (score 0):

You have a semicolon right in front of the `if` statement. In languages like C or C++ it would mean that the if statement would do nothing but C# treats it as an error. Because the code inside the curly braces does not belong to the `if` statement, because of the semicolon, the `else` keyword can't be there.

## Edit

Also, your `else if`s should be after closing the curly braces